# Work on a parameter in-place in C++ function

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

I'm adding a helper function to a class which is defined by a third-party library. This function modifies the object in-place. If I were writing the function as a method, it would look like this:

```
myObject &doTheThing( int someParameter ) {
    myProperty = someParameter;
    return *this;
}
```

so it can be called like:

```
myInstance = instance1 + instance2;
myInstance.doTheThing( );
```

or

```
display( (instance1 + instance2).doTheThing( ) );
```

Which works fine. But since I can't extend the object, I'm writing this as a helper function instead;

```
myObject &doTheThing( myObject &object, int someParameter ) {
    object.myProperty = someParameter;
    return object;
}
```

Which isn't valid in the second use-case because a temporary can't bind to a non-const reference (contrived test case: http://codepad.org/5frJjCUb). Is there a way around this without using pass-by-copy? If copying is the only way, is there some best-practice way to help the compiler optimise it properly? (C++11 is fine)

Comment: please write `myObject& doTheThing` (i.e. bind the `&` to the return type, not to the function), your layout is quite unconvential.

Comment: What do you expect this to do? What happens to the update `myProperty` once you have completed the `display` (and thus, the temporary object disappears)?

Comment: Your function is returning a reference regardless where you put the ampersand. I think the point was that it is more common (and thus more immediately obvious) to see it next to the type. Case in point, I mistakenly thought it returned a myObject by value until I saw that ampersand over to the right.

Comment: @Joel, TemplateRex: a habit I've carried over from defining variables, where I always put the `*` and `&` with the variable, to guard against mistakes like `int* a, b;`

Comment: @MatsPetersson I expect it to make some change to the result of `instance1+instance2`, which is passed to display, which will take it as a const reference and do some display-related stuff with it. After that, it is discarded. I should have mentioned that `display` took a const reference.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas My comment was only about layout, not about semantics. Are you saying that you always write the `&` next to the function name, instead of next to the return type?

Comment: @TemplateRex: Sorry, the *unconventional* location of the `&` in the original code made me think that he was returning a value and you proposed a reference. Removed the comment. Sorry for that :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Well that was exactly how the OP confused me as well, so it's a case of transitive confusion ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it by using the c++11 `rvalue`.

> The purpose of r-value reference parameters is to detect specifically when an object is an r-value. Because if an object is an r-value, then the function knows it won't be used again, so it can do whatever it wants with it.

You can overload the function :

```
myObject &doTheThing( myObject &object, int someParameter ) {
    object.myProperty = someParameter;
    return object;
}

myObject &doTheThing( myObject &&object, int someParameter ) {
    //                         ^^
    object.myProperty = someParameter;
    return object;
}
```

Keep your implementation and just add the one with the `rvalue` because when the detection I was talking about at the beginning is not taking place, you have to have a function taking a`lvalue` ref.

For example :

```
doTheThing( instance1 + instance2, 1 ) // uses the rvalue implementation
doTheThing( myInstance, 1);            // uses the lvalue implementation
```

**EDIT :**
<del>As it is said in the comment, you can skip the overload implementation</del> but this leads to a final problem : Using the `rvalue` reference seems to solve the problem but if we look further : the temporary objet created with `(instance1 + instance2)` will be destroyed after the execution of `doTheThing`. A solution could be :

```
myObject &doTheThing( myObject &object, int someParameter ) {
    object.myProperty = someParameter;
    return object;
}

myObject doTheThing( myObject &&object, int someParameter ) {
    //  ^
    object.myProperty = someParameter;
    return object;
}
```

The return by value of the overload will avoid some life issues.

But you can't skip the overload implementation now because the compiler generate this error :

```
error C2664: 'concat' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'MyObj' to 'MyObj &&'
    You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference
```

Comment: I though of this, but it is a bit of a convoluted design (probably due to issues with wanting a function that returns a reference be callable with an rvalue). At any rate you can skip the implementation of the overload that takes the rvalue-reference by forwarding the call to the lvalue version: `T& do(T&& obj, int p) { return do(obj,p); }`

Comment: You want to accept an r-value, according to your question. There are pretty much only two ways to do that: pass-by-r-value-reference or pass-by-copy. What are you looking for if not that?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas It is correct, it is a bit complicated for a simple thing like that. But it permits to keep the optimisation of the `pass-by-ref`. I edited my post with the skip of the overload implementation.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for (my updated test: http://ideone.com/OY9bPH)

Comment: As pointed out in Ralph Tandetzky's answer, maybe you should not return a reference for the second overload (with rvalue ref param), like `myObject doTheThing( myObject &&object, int someParameter )`. This will help doing the right thing with the return value and is less error prone for lifetime issues.

Comment: So the rvalue form can't even return an lvalue reference? I was under the impression that the issues stemmed from returning an rvalue which could then be assigned elsewhere.

Comment: @Dave No the `rvalue` overload can't event return a reference because the temporary object is destroyed after the execution of the function. It would lead on an *Undefined behaviour* to use it after that.

Comment: @PierreFourgeaud The temporary is destroyed at the end of the *full-expression* that includes the function call, not after the function call returns. The problem I wanted to point out is indeed that the return value of the second overload shouldn't be an lvalue because it would be copied, not moved, when assigned, and it shouldn't be an rvalue ref for the reason Ralph pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

You can overload your helper function to take also a rvalue reference, which will work in the second case:

```
myObject &doTheThing( myObject &&object, int someParameter ) {
    object.myProperty = someParameter;
    return object;
}
```

Mind that you need both versions of the function: the one taking a reference and the one taking a rvalue reference.

Comment: Same comment as in Pierre's answer, you don't need to implement the second overload, you can just forward to the first. Then again, I am not happy with a design in which a function will return an lvalue reference to an rvalue object...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I agree with the forwarding. As for the design, I can think of no other way to respect OP's wishes. It may not be a good design, but we cannot know it without more information about the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

### Take the argument by value and return by value

Change your code to

```
myObject doTheThing( myObject object, int someParameter ) {
    object.myProperty = someParameter;
    return object;
}
```

and everything should work just fine. Since C++11 the object will be simply moved into your parameter list, if created from a temporary. The same applies to the return value. In your case the compiler may even choose to elide the move-constructions and avoid the two moves all together depending on the context of the call.

This changes the meaning of `doTheThing(bla, blub)` changes obviously. If you want to modify an object using this function, then you have to write

```
bla = doTheThing( bla, blub );
```

instead. This does not look as nice, but offers value semantics which is better to reason about. But it solves your problem without the following pitfall.

### R-value references are no solution

At the first sight it seems that you can solve this with rvalue references, but **this turns out to be unsafe.** If you define the two functions

```
myObject &  doTheThing( myObject &  object, int someParameter );
myObject && doTheThing( myObject && object, int someParameter );
```

then writing

```
auto && obj = doTheThing( createTemporary(), 5 );
doSomethingElse( obj );
```

will extend the lifetime of the returned reference to the scope of `obj`. However, the object created by `createTemporary()` will be destroyed at the end of the first line. Hence accessing `obj` in the second line will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: "will extend the lifetime of the returned reference" there's no such thing in C++ that I'm aware of. The lifetime of *temporaries* can be extended, but AFAIK references don't even have a lifetime (that's a property of an *object*). A solution to the problem you mention is simply to return a new instance, i.e. no reference: `myObject doTheThing(myObject&& object, int someParam);`

Comment: When you write something like `const X & obj = f()` where `f()` returns an object by value whose type is `X` or some derived type, then the life-time of the returned object will be extended to the end of the scope in which `obj` lives and the correct destructor will be called. This works already in C++03. The same applies, if you use `auto &&`. If `f()` would return a reference, then the life-time will not be enlengthened which gives you undefined behavior. This doesn't happen very often, but it can happen. I've learned by experience that there's safety in value semantics.

Comment: In my case move is just as slow as copy, because the object doesn't use pointers to refer to data. I'm quite happy to use rvalues and simply be aware of the risks; it's not difficult to avoid those situations.

Comment: Fair enough. It's just a general recommendation to avoid returning references, especially short lived ones. If I were you I would avoid the second overload which takes an R-value reference and instead force client code to put a local variable there. It's the safe way to go. If that is not handy for your situation for any reason, then go for it.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky Ok, I didn't know about a special rule in [basic.stc]/3 that defines the *lifetime of references* (AFAIK they're NOT objects). I knew of the lifetime extensions, yet the problem is NOT the lifetime of the reference. This lifetime won't be extended, only the lifetime of a **temporary** could be extended. You're right that the _lifetime of the *temporary*_ won't be extended in this case, as it is bound to a function argument by ref [class.temporary]/5.